# MATLAB: RGB to white and black image

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I have an image which is `160x64x3`. This image has gray points and other colors. What I want is to convert the gray parts to 0 and the other parts to 1.

The image is below:

[image]

what I did is below but I think it is not certain because maybe there are some points which are the same for all red, green and blue. Is there a special function for this?

```
~((image(:,:,1)==image(:,:,2))&(image(:,:,1)==image(:,:,3))&(image(:,:,2)==image(:,:,3)))
```

Comment: Can't you just find out the intensity value for gray color and set it to 0 and the rest to 1 ?

Comment: Surely you just take the saturation (which will be zero for grey pixels) and threshold it at zero which will make everything non-grey into white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any special function, but the solution is pretty straightforward:

```
I = imread('sLUp2.png'); %Read source image.

%Initialize all destination pixels to 1
J = ones(size(I,1), size(I,2));

%Set to zero pixels which are gray in I (where Red==Green and Red==Blue).
J((I(:,:,1) == I(:,:,2)) & (I(:,:,1) == I(:,:,3))) = 0;
```

In the above solution all source gray-scale pixels with R=G=B, are considered gray.
For example: black pixel: (0,0,0), white pixel (255,255,255) and (x,x,x) are considered gray...

---

In case you want to find only the single common gray level (not all "gray-scale" pixels), you can do (something) as follows:

```
R = I(:, :, 1); %Red color plane.
Gray = R((I(:,:,1) == I(:,:,2)) & (I(:,:,1) == I(:,:,3))); %All values in which R=G=B.
H = imhist(Gray, 256); %Collect histogram of Gray.
common_gray = find(H == max(H)) - 1; %Find the most common gray value in histogram.

%Now, set only common_gray pixels to zero in destination image J.
J = ones(size(I,1), size(I,2));
J(R == common_gray) = 0;
```

In your image the common gray level ("gray points") equals **128**.

[image]

Comment: It's not explicitly stated, but it's unlikely the gray 'mask' is not known. So presumably  the solution is as simple as filtering for an exact rgb tuple. Also, worth pointing out that the top solution will also include "black" along with the gray points, which given the example image seems not the intention.

Comment: This doesn't give a perfect solution. See this for some examples: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HNakC.png and compare that with the original image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LUVYL.png

Comment: @Sardar_Usama You are probably right. I guess what Toygan intended is the second solution, where (0,0,0) and (255,255,255) are not considered gray.

Comment: I think it was, originally, the concern of the OP too which seems to be solved in the edited solution.